# Why does SQL Server use this index?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

I have two indexes on a table with 786602 rows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX1] 
ON [dbo].[O] ([A] ASC, [B] ASC)
INCLUDE ([c1], [c2], [c3]) 
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
           SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX2] 
ON [dbo].[O]([A] ASC, [B] ASC)
INCLUDE ([c1], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5], [c6], [c7], [c8], [c9], [c10]) 
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
           SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The following queries both use IX2:

```
select [c1], [c2], [c3] 
from [O] 
where A = 9 AND B = 10

select [c1], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5], [c6], [c7], [c8], [c9], [c10] 
from [O] 
where A = 9 AND B = 10
```

Disabling IX2 shows that query 1 then uses IX1 with the same performance.

Why does the first query not use IX1 as it seems to PERFECTLY match the requirements?

Is SQL Server really that smart and does not use it to show me that it can be removed?  :-)

Is it save to just DROP X1? (that was my original intention so I started testing the usage and just wondered why X1 is never used)

Comment: The columns' types might be relevant. Please add the `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: The first query will benefit from using either index, although the 1st index will be better for it (marginally better, depending on the 7 extra column sizes). I guess that since the 2nd query benefits much more from the 2nd index, the index is in memory, after the 2nd query is executed. So SQL Server is smart enough to use the (loaded in memory, 2nd) index instead of the on disk (1st) index. If you keep running only the 1st query for a long time (with various A and B parameters), it may switch using the 1st index instead.

Comment: Yes, try query 1 after clearing both the plan cache and dropping buffers (or simply restart the instance). I'm assuming this is a test box or local workstation, not production.

Comment: Yes of course it is a test box. After dropping and recreationg both they are used as one would expect. Good. However I will drop the IX1 in production since I know now they are kind of redundant.

Comment: Before blindly dropping the index in production, you may want to look at sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to determine if it is in fact being used more often than the larger index.

Comment: ypercube - Have you considered to put your answer into the answer field? :)

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot confirm this with any official documentation, the reason must be based on the total size of included columns and the cost.

With the test i conducted, the indexes with 10 columns and 3 columns had exactly the same cost and logical/physical reads, which I assumed to be the same with the original poster's environment.  I gradually increased the size of the 4th column, and at certain point, the opimizer started choosing the 1st index for the 1st statement.  The table used had about 55k rows.

This only shows an anecdotal evidence and a theory on certain behavior of the optimizer.  I hope  someone who really knows the meanism of it will explain us all why, if this theory isn't correct.